# ¿Cómo solucionar el error mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, flask, nginx, gunicorn

Tengo una aplicación web en Flask y Mysql 8, utilizo gunicorn para correr el servidor local y un proxy_pass con nginx 1.14.1

Funciona todo muy bien por un tiempo (horas, 1 a 3 días). Sin embargo, en algún momento se produce un error y no se puede conectar a mysql.

He revisado el servicio mysqld con `systemctl status mysqld`  y todo está ok, es más, tengo otra app en php 7 en el mismo  servidor y no tiene ningún problema.

Si reinicio el servicio de la aplicación funciona correctamente, pero el problema persiste después de un tiempo.

Mi sistema operativo  es centos 8.

**Este es el log de mi app:**

```
Exception on /api/tracking/_rows [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/admin/virtual/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 489, in cmd_query
    raw_as_string=raw_as_string)
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: MySQL server has gone away
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/admin/virtual/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/var/www/admin/virtual/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/var/www/admin/virtual/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/var/www/admin/virtual/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/var/www/admin/virtual/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/var/www/admin/virtual/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/var/www/admin/app.py", line 104, in run_service
    result=auto_action(request)
  File "/var/www/admin/core/Data_grid.py", line 60, in _rows
    self.db.execute(query.format(filters))
  File "/var/www/admin/virtual/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 266, in execute
    raw_as_string=self._raw_as_string)
  File "/var/www/admin/virtual/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 492, in cmd_query
    sqlstate=exc.sqlstate)
mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
```

**Este es el contenido de mi archivo .service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve admin 
After=network.target
[Service]
User=root
Group=nginx
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/admin
Environment="PATH=/var/www/admin/virtual/bin"
ExecStart=/var/www/admin/virtual/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:admin.sock -m 007 app:app
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Este es mi configuración en nginx**

```
server {
        server_name admin.mydoamin.com www.admin.mydoamin.com;
        location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/var/www/admin/admin.sock;
        }
}
```

Agradezco su ayuda de antemano, no tengo idea de porque se cae la conexión de mysql con flask

Comment: ¿Te es útil [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18979736/12788110)?

Answer (score 3):

Tu error no tiene que ver ni con `Flask`m `Gunicorn` ni `Nginx` Como bien indica la traaza,el error radica en MySQL. **Debes de agregar la siguiente linea al archivo** `my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=128M
```

Se encuentra según el sistema operativo en las siguientes direcciones:

**Windows**

`C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0`

**Linux**

`/etc/mysql`

## Explicación

Este problema se produce cuando se trata de trabjar en MySQL con columnas muy grandes, por lo que tienes que aumentar el máximo de paquetes, para que MySQL pueda trabajar con dichas preguntas.

Está explicado en la [documentación de MySQL aquí.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-features-max-allowed-packet.html)

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. La configuración de Mysql ya tenía "max_allowed_packet=2048M", mi sistema operativo  es centos 8.

Comment: Es raro, ese tipo de error se debe a esa parte de la configuiración, te he actualizado la respuesta, añadiendotte ```[mysqld]``` por si acaso te falta. Aunque normalmente los equipos actuales soportan bastante más memoria, es posible que no tengas 2 teras disponibles? y por tanto debas bajar el ```max_allowed_packet```?

Comment: Hola, si tiene [mysqld]  y tambien 2048MB no sería 2GB?
el siguiente comando me dice que tengo 2.7GB libres.                                                                                        
`[root@centos-8 ~]# free -m -h
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          3.8Gi       679Mi       2.5Gi       208Mi       730Mi       2.8Gi
Swap:            0B          0B          0B`

Comment: Perdona, quería decir 2GB. Yo cuando he tenido ese tipo de problema ha venido de ahí. Intenta bajarlo 2GB es un valor demasiado alto. Pero si no te funciona, lo único que se me ocurre es que reinstales de nuevo...

Comment: @EmerIsau ¿2GB no es demasiado? Con `128MB` o `64MB` debería bastar. Agrega también más tiempo de espera, por ejemplo: `wait_timeout = 6000`. Sea como sea, deberías identificar los procesos lentos y optimizar. A veces ese error puede ocurrir por problemas de compatibilidad entre versiones, o de collation entre tablas que quieres volcar en otra tablas.

Comment: He reducido a `128MB`  pero seguía igual, investigando encontré que era porque no se estaba cerrando  la conexión  a la base de datos. Soy nuevo en Flask, ¿Cada vez que se haga una petición a la API se tiene que abrir y cerrar la base de datos? ¿es posible mantener la conexión abierta siempre en una variable global?

Comment: @EmerIsau parece que sí es posible tener una conexión persistente. [Revisa este enlace](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/0.12.x/tutorial/dbcon/) donde se explica la forma correcta de hacerlo.